# Endpoint returning object instead of direct JSON

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch the value of `ServiceProvider` in my component but instead I am getting `undefined` because `ServiceProvider` is inside `return` and I don't know how to fetch the value.

```
return: {     
 issuerName: "ABC",
 ServiceProvider: "1"     
}
```

instead of

```
{     
 issuerName: "ABC",
 ServiceProvider: "1"     
}
```

My code in component is as below

```
this.validateService.getDataResponse(getData).subscribe(response => {
   if (response.data.serviceProvider == '1' || response.data.serviceProvider == '2') { 
      //... Some login here ...//
   }
}
```

If I write `data.return.serviceProvider` it gives me an error saying "Property does not exist on type `'GetDataResponse'`"

Here's GetDataResponse :

```
export class GetDataResponse {
  public data: DataObj;
}
```

DataObj:

```
export class DataObj{
  public issuerName: string;
  public serviceProvider: string;
}
```

I am an angular developer with very basic knowledge on SpringBoot. Please help me get the response directly.

Comment: Data.return.ServiceProvider

Comment: please post your service...anyway maybe  if (response.serviceProvider == '1' || response.serviceProvider == '2') try this

Comment: Can you show the controller code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s funny that the answer was so simple. It was right there in front of my eyes.

Issue: 
How to retrieve a key inside an object when you get object as a response.

Solution:
It’s simple object reference.

To refer to `return` write `response[‘return’].serviceProvider`

GetDataResponse -

`export class GetDataResponse {`

`public issuerName: string;`

`public serviceProvider: string;`

`}`